# Does 刚开始工作的时候... mean "when starting work" (each day) or "when entering the workforce"?

Tags: meaning

This is from HSK4上 (page 49):

> [image: 刚开始工作的时候，什么最重要？]
>   刚开始工作的时候，什么最重要？
>   What is most important when I first started working?  ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E5%88%9A%E5%BC%80%E5%A7%8B%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E7%9A%84%E6%97%B6%E5%80%99%EF%BC%8C%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E6%9C%80%E9%87%8D%E8%A6%81%EF%BC%9F))

I'm confused here: I can't tell whether this means:

1. "when starting work" (perhaps each workday) or
2. "when entering the workforce" (as in, first day of work, perhaps in my life, or perhaps at a new company).

My impression from context that it has the second meaning (it's related to a passage which begins 年轻人刚开始工作的时候，不要太急着赚钱...), but I don't know how I could figure that out.

**Question**: Does 刚开始工作的时候... mean "when starting work" (each day) or "when entering the workforce"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 刚开始工作的时候，什么最重要？

I'd interpret it as *when entering the workforce*, which  is the second meaning you listed.

When someone says 刚开始工作的时候, I'd assume he meant *when entering the workforce*.  If they try to convey *when starting work each workday*, I'd expect something like: 每天早上开始工作的时候; 每天开始工作的时候; 每天开始工作时; 每天工作开始时.

One could bend that rule/convention sometimes, but it's not hard to figure out what they really mean in a given context anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote: "在开始工作的时候什么最重要" the sentence would be ambiguous:

"在开始工作的时候" could mean at the start of your work shift: e.g. "在开始作的时候最重的要是检查安全"(When you start to work, the most important thing is check safety)

It could also mean when you start entering the work force: e.g. "在开始工作的时候最重要的是與同事打好關係" (When you entering the work force, the most important thing is creating a good relationship with colleagues)

Since (在)开始工作的时候最重的要是检查安全 means (每天)开始工作的时候最重的要是检查安全. And you can't replace "每天"(everyday) with "刚" (just), "刚开始工作的时候" should be  interpreted as "when first entering the work force"

Answer (score 1):

Not 'each day', but 'at the beginning'.

刚开始工作的时候，什么最重要？
What's the most important thing when you just start off in a new job?